# How to remove my app from - history apps (that was launched)

Tags: android, history, activity-finish

how can I remove my app from the history app
(history - by long press the home button)

I look and done some things I saw, but it doesnt work, and I still see my app in the history.

I call to `finish()`

```
onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        int id= android.os.Process.myPid();
        android.os.Process.killProcess(id);
}
```

in `manifest` i wrote:

```
<application
    ...
    android:persistent="true"
    android:noHistory="true"

     <activity
        ...
        android:name="com.example.android.activityrecognition.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement this from your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, just adding `android:noHistory="true"` attribute in those `<activity>` you want.

Comment: it's still dont make effect

Comment: wait wait i wrote in manifest activity more things, when i delete them.. it's works grate. thank you!